# when running the java program, report cannot find class

Tags: java

The file `FactoryDemo.java` is compiled successfully and in it there  is the

```
package home.city.Desktop.factorydemo;
```

I compile it by using `javac -d / FactoryDemo.java` and nothing wrong is reported.

But when I try to run it by using `java home.city.Desktop.factorydemo.FactoryDemo`, it reports：

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: home/city/Desktop/factorydemo/FactoryDemo
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: home.city.Desktop.factorydemo.FactoryDemo
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: home.city.Desktop.factorydemo.FactoryDemo. Program will exit.
```

I have tried many times but I could not find the solution to the problem. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: is there actually a main class in that file?

Answer (score 1):

Your compiled class must be in a directory called:
`home/city/Desktop/factorydemo`

On Unix, just run this:
`mkdir -p home/city/Desktop/factorydemo; mv FactoryDemo.class home/city/Desktop/factorydemo/`

For best practice, simply move your Java source file in that folder too so the compiler outputs the file to the right spot.

Comment: You do not need to create directories manually, "javac -d" command create them all automatically.

Comment: @mmc18, you are right...but do you know the reason why it reports exceptions when running?

Comment: Yeap, class is not found, since jvm searches class in current directory. Therefore you have to point out correct path of Class file. I mean root directory has to be in classpath.

Answer (score 1):

FactoryDemo Class is created under root directory, you should type following command ( . instead of /)

```
javac -d . FactoryDemo.java
```

It creates `home.city.Desktop.factorydemo` directories starting from current directory.

If you want class created under root directory. You must type following command to execute.

```
java -classpath / home.city.Desktop.factorydemo.FactoryDemo
```

Comment: In fact, I wanna create the directory under root directory, not current directory....